# Rundeck - Using Tags in Nodes gives an error when running the job

Tags: tags, nodes, rundeck

In Rundeck within a Job I used the following value under Nodes - Node Filter.
[tags:${option.server_env}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNH44.png)

My tags are defined under Workflow - Options:

```
Option type: Text

Option name: server_env

Allowed values: List (Defined my tags over there)

List delimiter: ,
```

My tags are defined as well under the Project settings - [Edit nodes..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeIdc.png)

When I open my job, select my chosen tag and run my job I retrieve the
[following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfr6Y.png).

The following plugin is [installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChBus.png).

How can I get it to work that nodes are a variable value so I can use 1 job for multiple tags (environments)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example based on this three-nodes model source.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <node name="node00" description="Node 00" tags="db" hostname="192.168.56.20" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck" />
  <node name="node01" description="Node 01" tags="db" hostname="192.168.56.21" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck" />
  <node name="node02" description="Node 02" tags="bk" hostname="192.168.56.22" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck" />
</project>
```

It works in this way.

1. Create a job with an option, the option must contain a [list of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O098l.jpg), a [default value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8V5L.jpg) and, a [delimiter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX9SF.jpg) (a comma in my example). Also, the job must be dispatched to a node using the node tag in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gITYV.jpg) way.
2. Save the job.
3. First test: run the job just using the [default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVjHw.jpg) value, the job is dispatched only to the `bk` [tagged nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2oMp.jpg).
4. Second test: select [all options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4WyP.jpg), then the job is dispatched to [all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLOjC.jpg) nodes (`db` and `bk` tagged nodes).

Here the job definition example to test.

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 3ebd683d-4f0a-42ae-8d32-2be22fbb9ae5
  loglevel: INFO
  name: JobDispatchedToNodes
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: tags:${option.mynodes}
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  options:
  - delimiter: ','
    enforced: true
    multivalued: true
    name: mynodes
    required: true
    value: db
    values:
    - db
    - bk
    valuesListDelimiter: ','
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  schedules: []
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: uname -a
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 3ebd683d-4f0a-42ae-8d32-2be22fbb9ae5
```